# Bet sizing to actual orders

Tags: machine-learning, quants, position-sizing, betting

At chapter 10.2 in *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* it says:

> Suppose that one strategy produced a sequence of bet sizes $[m_{1,1}, m_{1,2}, m_{1,3}] = [.5, 1, 0]$, as the market price followed a sequence $[p_1, p_2, p_3] = [1, .5, 1.25]$, where $p_t$ is the price at time $t$. The other strategy produced a sequence $[m_{2,1} , m_{2,2} , m_{2,3} ] = [1, .5, 0]$, as it was forced to reduce its bet size once the market moved against the initial full position. Both strategies produced forecasts that turned out to be correct (the price increased by 25% between $p_1$ and $p_3$), however the first strategy made money (0.5) while the second strategy lost money (−.125).

I'm trying to figure out how this actually translates to number of shares to buy and sell given a budget as it appears to not be what intuition would dictate.

Taking the first example i.e. bet sizes .5, 1, 0 and a budget of \$1, we start first by wagering half of our budget at a price of \$1 so .5 shares. Then at $t_2$ we wager everything meaning the \$.5 we have left over so now we have 1.5 shares. And then at $t_3$ we sell everything. But this produces a final budget of \$1.875 not the \$1.5 stated ("however the first strategy made money (0.5)" i.e. \$1.50).

In order to arrive at \$1.50, at $t_1$ we again stake \$.5 so that's .5 shares. Then at $t_2$ we stake 1 (100%) of our current position (not the remaining budget as intuition might indicate) which is now worth \$.25 so that's another .5 shares, leaving us with a budget of \$.25. Then at $t_3$, we sell everything i.e. 1 share at 1.25 = 1.25 + .25 remaining budget = \$1.5. The same approach yields -.125 for the second strategy (at $t_2$ we sell half of our current position)

Is this interpretation correct? If so, how would a negative bet size be interpreted. For instance if the series was 1, -.2, 0 does this mean:

$t_1$: wager everything

$t_2$: sell everything and go short .2 the original long position size

$t_3$: cover the short

Comment: I believe, as seen in articles about the Kelly Criterion, that the bet $m$ represents the fraction of the *bankroll* (or in other words *of your total wealth at the time*) that is wagered on an asset. I do not believe it is based on "the original long position size".

Comment: that makes more sense but then given 1, .5, 0, how would you wager .5 of nothing? or is it assumed full bets or close to it will never happen?

Comment: [1,0.5,0] => You start with a full position (m=1). Unfortunately the price goes from p=1 to p=0.5 so you lose half your wealth (P&L=-0.5, current wealth=0.5 (not zero like you said)). Now you want a half position (m=0.5) so you sell half of what you have; you now have 0.25 in the stock and 0.25 in cash. The price  goes from p=0.5 to p=1.25 so you end up with 0.25*(1.25/0.5) in stock and 0.25 in cash. Total wealth is 0.875 so overall P&L is 1-0.875 = -0.125 as Marcos wrote.

Comment: The betting strategy [1,1,1,1,...] is what people call Buy and Hold: you invest all your money in the stock and then you just hold, never selling or buying any shares. At all times all your wealth is in the stock and you have no cash. Your wealth fluctuates up and down proportionally to the stock price.

Comment: @noob2 that makes sense for that case but for the other [0.5, 1, 0] you get +.875 not +.50